# What is the most efficient way to compare a table against itself in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have recently developed some coding that will identify first call resolution for an insurance company that I currently work for. The code basically creates two identical SELECT statements from a call data table, sorts and ranks the data by a `member_id`, `call_date` and `call_time` and then compares each query against one another where the member_id and call_type are equal, but the "rank" or `RowId` is not (so the comparison happens for each `Rowid` from one side of the inner join to the other but not for the same `Rowid`). This acts as a quasi "loop" to compare all the records to see where the `call_dates are > 14` days OR where the `call_dates` are equal AND the `call_times are > 24` hours....for the same `call_type` and same `member_id`.

```
Here is a sample of the code:

DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
[MEM_ID] [varchar](10) NULL,
       [CALL_DATE] [datetime2](3) NULL,
       [CALL_TIME] [varchar](8) NULL,
       [OPER_CODE] [varchar](8) NULL,
       [TEXT_DEPT] [varchar](6) NULL,
       [CAT_DESC] [varchar](30) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
VALUES ('00000-1400', '2018-07-16 00:00:00.000','10:12:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','PLAN BENEFITS')
,('00000-1400', '2018-06-10 00:00:00.000','10:12:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','PLAN BENEFITS')
,('00000-1400', '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000','18:12:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','CLAIMS')
,('00000-1400', '2018-07-02 00:00:00.000','05:12:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','OTHER')
,('00000-1400', '2018-07-14 00:00:00.000','02:12:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','CLAIMS')
,('00000-1400', '2018-07-27 00:00:00.000','11:12:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','PLAN BENEFITS')
,('00000-1400', '2018-06-30 00:00:00.000','08:12:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','PLAN BENEFITS')
,('00000-1400', '2018-06-29 00:00:00.000','07:12:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','AUTHORIZATIONS')
,('00000-1400', '2018-06-29 00:00:00.000','07:26:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','AUTHORIZATIONS')
,('00000-1400', '2018-06-25 00:00:00.000','09:38:23','YYZ2500','SERV06','OTHER')


Select Calc.*, CASE WHEN Calc.Disposition = 'No subsequent within 14' THEN CONVERT(tinyint, 1) ELSE 0 END as FCR_Ind

From  (Select DISTINCT Final.RowID, Final.CallCount, Final.MEM_ID, Final.CALL_DATE, 
    Final.CALL_TIME, Final.CAT_DESC, Final.OPER_CODE, Final.TEXT_DEPT,
       CASE WHEN Final.[Had a subsequent within 14 days] IS NULL 
       THEN 'No subsequent within 14' ELSE Final.[Had a subsequent within 14 days]
       END as Disposition
       From  (Select *
 From (Select DISTINCT T1.RowID, T1.CallCount, T1.MEM_ID, T1.CALL_DATE, 
    T1.CALL_TIME, T1.CAT_DESC, T1.OPER_CODE, T1.TEXT_DEPT,
CASE WHEN T2.CALL_DATE BETWEEN T1.CALL_DATE AND DateAdd(DAY, 14, T1.CALL_DATE) AND T2.RowID <> T1.RowID AND T2.CALL_DATE <> T1.CALL_DATE OR T2.CALL_TIME BETWEEN T1.CALL_TIME AND DateAdd(HOUR, 24, T1.CALL_DATE) AND T2.RowID <> T1.RowID AND T2.CALL_DATE = T1.CALL_DATE THEN 'Had a subsequent within 14 days' END as Disposition                                                           
               From   (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY MEM_ID,
              [CALL_DATE], CALL_TIME) AS RowID, Count(CALL_TIME) as CallCount,
  MEM_ID, [CALL_DATE], CALL_TIME, CAT_DESC, OPER_CODE, TEXT_DEPT
                       From @Temp
                       Group by MEM_ID, [CALL_DATE], CALL_TIME, CAT_DESC, OPER_CODE, 
                    TEXT_DEPT) as T1
        Inner Join  (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY MEM_ID, 
                [CALL_DATE], CALL_TIME) AS RowID, Count(CALL_TIME) as
                CallCount, MEM_ID, [CALL_DATE], CALL_TIME, CAT_DESC,
                OPER_CODE, TEXT_DEPT
    From @Temp
                Group by MEM_ID, [CALL_DATE], CALL_TIME, CAT_DESC, OPER_CODE,
        TEXT_DEPT) as T2
                      ON   T1.MEM_ID = T2.MEM_ID AND T1.CAT_DESC = T2.CAT_DESC ) as Sub 

      PIVOT( MAX(Sub.Disposition)
FOR Sub.Disposition IN ([Had a subsequent within 14 days])) AS PivotTable) as Final) as Calc
```

The Output yields the following:
[image: SQL output]

I know this is not the most efficient way to solve this problem and was wondering if there is a way to write the INNER JOIN portion where only 1 of the sorted tables is used to iterate thru out the records of the 2nd sorted table instead of each table iterating against each other? I appreciate any insights on how to make this code use less system resources and make it more efficient from an execution plan standpoint. 
    Thanks!!

Comment: Why is this important --> T2.RowID <> T1.RowID ?

Comment: how many records are there in table ?Will you process all data in one time or only part of data like using paging or filter data .

Comment: I think your output is wrong,in that case show your desire output .

Comment: Hello Ross, that enables the query to look at the next record since it doesn't need to look at the same exact record from each table.

Comment: Hi Kumar, there could be millions of records given the date parameters that one could apply. And I have tested the output and it is giving the desired outcome. The code is looking for the same MEM_ID and CAT_DESC within 14 days for that MEM_ID. If that condition is false, then the call was resolved the 1st time and shows a "1" in the FCR_Ind field. If another call came in within 14 days for the same MEM_ID and CAT_DESC...then the original call was not resolved and the FCR_Ind should reflect as a "0".